# Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction ( Realm + Android )

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have implement the following method to update `UserProfile` from realm db.

```
override fun updateCurrentUser(userProfile: UserProfile, successAction: () -> Unit) {
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(
                object : Realm.Transaction {
                    override fun execute(realm: Realm) {

                        val user = realm.where(UserProfile::class.java).equalTo("userName", userProfile.userName).findFirst()
                        user?.firstName = userProfile.firstName
                        user?.lastName = userProfile.lastName
                        user?.gender = userProfile.gender
                        user?.height = userProfile.height
                        user?.weight = userProfile.weight
                        user?.dob = userProfile.dob
                        user?.firstTimeSetupDone = true

                    }
                },
                object : Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess {
                    override fun onSuccess() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Saved User successfully with $userProfile")
                        successAction()
                    }

                },
                object : Realm.Transaction.OnError {
                    override fun onError(error: Throwable?) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error saving user", error)
                    }
                }
        )
    }
```

But it throws the following error even though I'm executing it under `realm.executeTransactionAsync`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.
                                                                            at io.realm.internal.Table.throwImmutable(Table.java:674)
                                                                            at io.realm.internal.Table.checkImmutable(Table.java:549)
                                                                            at io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.setString(UncheckedRow.java:230)
                                                                            at io.realm.UserProfileRealmProxy.realmSet$firstName(UserProfileRealmProxy.java:209)
                                                                            at saukya.wellness.mobile.services.data.domain.UserProfile.setFirstName(UserProfile.kt:27)
                                                                            at saukya.wellness.mobile.ui.onboarding.OnBoardingPresenter.submitData(OnBoardingPresenter.kt:102)
                                                                            at saukya.wellness.mobile.ui.onboarding.OnBoardingActivity.submitData(OnBoardingActivity.kt:106)
                                                                            at saukya.wellness.mobile.ui.onboarding.OnBoardingHealthInfoFragment$setupNextButton$1.onClick(OnBoardingHealthInfoFragment.kt:86)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: You're getting the exception in `submitData`. This is `updateCurrentUser`

Answer (score 12):

Object queried by realm can't be modified, simple way to solve this problem is to new a object, copy realm object fields to this new one. If you want to persist，call insertOrUpdate method to save it in realm.

Answer (score 0):

you can call this to start transaction as error said you have to open write transaction:

```
realmObj.beginTransaction();
//do your updating stuff here
realmObj.commitTransaction();
```